# Backbone.Sharepoint.soap querySelector IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code coming from [this github project](https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint/issues/14)

```
    (function (Backbone, _, $) {

        // SharePoint ListData service
        var LIST_SERVICE = '_vti_bin/Lists.asmx',
            url,
            SoapClient;

        // calculate url based on site
        url = function (options) {
            var site = options.site,
            // remove leading and trailing forward slashes from the site path
                path = site.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, ''),
                url = (path ? '/' + path : '') + '/' + LIST_SERVICE;

            return url;
        };

        SoapClient = {
            tpl: _.template(
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                    '<soap:Envelope ' +
                    '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                    '  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                    '  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<soap:Body>' +
                    '<<%= method %> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">' +
                    '<%= params %>' +
                    '</<%= method %>>' +
                    '</soap:Body>' +
                    '</soap:Envelope>'
            ),

            serializeParams: function (params) {
                var key, value, xml = '';

                params = params || {};

                for (key in params) {
                    value = params[key];
                    if (value) {
                        xml += '<' + key + '>';
                        switch (key) {
                            case 'viewFields':
                                // for future use...
                                break;
                            default:
                                xml += params[key];
                                break;
                        }

                        xml += '</' + key + '>';
                    }
                }
                return xml;
            },

            success: function (data, status, xhr, callback) {
                var nodes, node, rootnode, name,
                    NODE_ELEMENT = 1,
                    attributes, attribute,
                    results = [], result,
                    root = 'data',
                    i, j;


                rootnode = data.querySelector(root);
                nodes = rootnode.childNodes;

                for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
                    node = nodes[i];

                    // skip text nodes
                    if (node.nodeType === NODE_ELEMENT) {
                        attributes = node.attributes;
                        result = {};
                        for (j = 0; j < attributes.length; j += 1) {
                            attribute = attributes[j];
                            name = attribute.name.replace('ows_', '');
                            result[name] = attribute.value;
                        }
                        // only use the result if it is not hidden
                        if ((result.Hidden || '').toUpperCase() !== "TRUE") {
                            results.push(result);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // results now contains an Array of javascript objects.

                // call the success handler inside Collection.fetch() to process the results.
                if (callback) {
                    callback(results, status, xhr);
                }

            },


            call: function (config) {
                var me = this,
                    request;


                config = config || {};

                // prepare the Ajax request
                request = {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url({ site: config.site }),
                    contentType: 'text/xml',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    data: this.tpl({
                        method: config.method,
                        params: this.serializeParams(config.params)
                    }),
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        me.success(data, status, xhr, config.success)
                    },
                    error: config.error
                };

                // Make the request.
                return $.ajax(request);

            }


        };


        Backbone.SP = {};

        Backbone.SP.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
            // to be implemented...
        });

        Backbone.SP.List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: function () {
                // otherwise use site and list settings of this collection
                return url({ site: this.site });

            },

            sync: function (method, collection, options) {

                SoapClient.call({
                    site: collection.site,
                    service: 'Lists',
                    method: 'GetListItems',
                    success: options.success,
                    error: options.error,
                    params: {
                        listName: collection.list,
                        viewName: collection.view || ''
                    }
                });


            }



        });


    } (Backbone, _, $));
```

There are issues with this approach:

It seems that the data response object is empty, this only happens in IE for some strange reason

I am looking for a way to refactor this code and make it work crossbrowser.

I really appreciate your help in this matter

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `querySelector` is supported in IE8.

Comment: Thanks Teemu, I guess its triggering querySelector error because the object is empty

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this [pull request](https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint/pull/12) solves the compatibility issues